# Real time updates from mongodb to Flutter web

Tags: mongodb, flutter-web

I'm building a web application in Flutter and working with mongodb. I'd like to activate code written in dart from my application right when there is a change in the mongodb database. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

zvi,
you can refer to this MongoDB Flutter (React of changes) official documentation here.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/realm-database/react-to-changes/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).